# Need to build custom metabox select prev posts by category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, metabox

I am working on a personal project and need the ability to select a previous post based on a selected category. This will be a site devoted to building  a pedigree. I really hope this makes sense. I am sitting here trying to think of the best way to describe what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to your question? may be few examples too will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are surely many other ways to archive something like this but the easiest - in my opinion - would be to [create](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) or [generate](http://generatewp.com/post-type/) a custom post type and the use of a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) which gives you the possibility to create a metabox with filtered post relations.

Comment: Going to give this a whirl and will write back after a go.

Comment: Ok. So I am not usually the guy to use many plug-ins. But in this case.... WOW! What a time saver! Thank you so much Realloc!